# Laravel:Class Error after restarting Vagrant (Homestead)

Tags: php, symfony, laravel

I have been working on the project for past few days. I use Vagrant (Homestead) to do the development work and it has been working great.

Today I have restarted my PC and execute a command `vagrant up`

When I access the url `www.domain.dev` and I get an error:

> Fatal error: Class 'Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request' not
>   found in
>   /home/vagrant/Code/project1/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Request.php
>   on line 6

First time I see this error.

I am lost here, how to solve this issue?

Comment: Try deleting your `vendors` directory and running `composer install` again.

Comment: @DavidT That have fixed it thanks.. what was causing this problem?

Comment: you may have just lost a file in there by mistake. If that has fixed the problem I will write an answer can you mark as correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated above in the comments, you may have lost a file in your `vendors` directory by mistake. When ever you receive an error stating something is not found in a `vendors/*` directory you can just delete the whole `vendors` directory and use `composer install` to get a fresh set of files.